# Reference a statement from one subroutine in another

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, reference

I have code that I broke into multiple pieces that run in order.  I start with a Message Box that asks **"Are you entering data for August"**. If the answer is 'yes' it runs a series of codes, but now that my code is too long I'm unable to continue that series of code for the month of August.  I'm trying to make the change in code seamless.  When the new code begins I could have it ask again "what month are you entering data for" but if possible I'd like not to.  Ideally I want the first line of my new code to be "If you answered Yes to the initial question in code one then proceed".

Here's where I call all the code:

```
Sub PreScrub()
Call Tabs
Call AUGSUMMCEND
Call AugNUR
End Sub
```

The first code is just formatting, so I'll skip that.  Here's the beginning of my second code where I prompt for the month:

```
Augbox = MsgBox("Are you entering Prescrub for August?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
If Augbox = vbYes Then

For i = 1 To recvarSumm.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To recvarSumm.Rows.Count
If recvarSumm.Cells(i, j).Value = "Aetna" Then
    recvarSummvalues.Cells(i, j).Range("A1:C1").Copy
    wsYTDSUMM.Columns(1).Find("Aetna").Offset(9, 1).PasteSpecial
End If
    Next j
Next i
```

The code carries on from there for a long time.  Then I want the beginning of my `AugNur` code to say "If Augbox from AUGSUMMCEND is 'yes' then continue".

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the code module, before the first procedure, enter this line:

```
Private Augbox As Long
```

Now make sure that you do NOT define `Augbox` again with any Dim statement in the procedures.

That's it.

The value of `Augbox` will now be shared between all procedures of the module.

Comment: So it will go before my Prescrub code, where I call each individual code?  I ask because then I would have to manually choose to run the Sub Prescrub() correct?

Comment: It will go before anything else, but it should not change how you run Prescrub() or anything else.